# Was fighter pilot training part of a Jedi Padawan's training during the times of the Galactic Republic?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, jedi-training

I am wondering if during the times of the Galactic Republic that it was a requirement that all Jedi Padawans had to learn how to pilot a fighter ship and learn fundamental dog-fighting skills in order to achieve the rank of Jedi Knight.

If so, it makes me wonder if all the Jedi Masters were capable of fighting in space battles. I would have loved to have seen Yoda in his own custom-sized fighter ship participating in the Battle over Coruscant in *Revenge of the Sith*.

Was fighter pilot training part of a Jedi Padawan's training during the times of the Galactic Republic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Jedi are pilots, but not all Jedi are ace starfighter pilots.

> JEDI STARSHIPS
>
> While the Jedi Order typically uses Republic cruisers for diplomatic missions across the galaxy, some assignments require smaller and less conspicuous transports. And because Jedi can't always rely on pilots to reach their destination, **Jedi training includes how to fly starships.** The Jedi Temple on Coruscant contains hangars for numerous vessels, including single-passenger starfighters. Although most Jedi starfighters are engineered to accommodate humanoid Jedi, some are designed for specific alien species.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Complete Vehicles](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Complete_Vehicles_(2018))</sup></sub>

and

> **Everybody thinks** they know what a Jedi is — that we all serve in the Army of Light and fight the Sith Lords, or **that we're all** lightsaber battlemasters and **starfighter aces.** **It just isn’t so.**
>
> <sub><sup>[The Jedi Path: A Manual for Students of the Force](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_(real-life_book))</sup></sub>

Comment: So, do you think it's safe to assume that they all trained to be starfighter pilots during their Jedi training because the Jedi Order owned starfighters?

Comment: @user255577 - Don't forget that we spend most of our time with Jedi royalty, those with extreme levels of ability in pretty much all areas. Most Jedi probably don't have the skill to do more than standard flying and maybe some basic combat/evasive skills.